# Is there any ajax debugger for IE8 other than Fiddler?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there any ajax debugger for IE8 other than Fiddler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can try Charles Proxy too. http://www.charlesproxy.com/

If you want to get really deep into web proxying, then you could also look at [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/Intro/). I've not used it on windows, but on linux it is massively configurable - you don't mention what you're after in specific, but if there is something that neither charles nor fiddler do, then you could look at using squid, and processing your HTTP requests with scripts, for example, which I guess is something you could get going with a bit of effort.

Some more options:

- [Parosproxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/), java based HTTP proxy (seems inactive project atm)
- [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) - generic network traffic inspector

Comment: any freewares?  as charlesprxy is a licensed one

Comment: added some more in edit. considering how good charles is, the license fee is really not so high.